# CSS trick- How to hide one tr if the upper tr is empty

Tags: html, css

i am having a table html like this

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="grid_row_content">
        <td class="gridCell">
            <div class="componentswitcher">
            <div style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grid_row_spacer"></tr>
    <tr class="grid_row_content">
        <td class="gridCell">
            <div class="componentswitcher">
            <div style="display:none;"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr><tr class="grid_row_spacer"></tr>
</tbody>
```

for the spacing between two tr i am having a tr class "grid_row_spacer" having css {height:4px}
it even takes it's height when it's above tr is empty and doesn't have any height,like this.
i need a css for "grid_row_spacer" that will take it's height when it's above tr is not empty.

Suggestion Please

Comment: it will not work bcz  <tr class="grid_row_spacer"></tr> haiving height of 4px

Answer (score 0):

You can modify element based on if it is empty or not with CSS selector `:empty`, but that works for empty elements without children, like so https://jsfiddle.net/entio/rmyqf0jo/1/

If You could change markup of the table based on its content, namely add some class to empty element, like:

```
<tr class="grid_row_content empty">
    ...
</tr>
<tr class="grid_row_spacer"></tr>
```

Then You use just `.grid_row_content.empty + .grid_row_spacer { display: none; }`

I am afraid this is not possible to achieve using only-CSS solution.

Comment: Hi @entio
had tried to implement this

table.grid_row_content.gridCell > div :empty + table.grid_row_spacer{
            display:none;
        }

not succeed..!!

any suggestion...??

Comment: @akvickyit7 what does that exactly mean that it does not work? Post some fiddle and maybe i will be able to help You